# PySpark: Use Secret from Spark Context

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I have multiple clusters where the secret is stored in the spark config such as

```
my.secret {{secrets/keyvault/sec1}}
```

Now I want to use the secret such as the following:

```
credential = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id="xxx", client_id=yyy, client_secret= spark.conf.get("my.secret"))
```

**However, this seems not to work (ClientSecretCredential.get_token failed -Invalid client secret provided). How can I use the secret from the context?**

With `dbutils.secrets.get(scope="keyvault", key="sec1")` everything works fine.

```
credential = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id="xxx", client_id=yyy, client_secret= dbutils.secrets.get(scope="keyvault", key="sec1"))
```

Also, when putting the secret in an env Variable everything works (mysec={{secrets/keyvault/sec1}} and usage via `os.getenv`)

```
credential = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id="xxx", client_id=yyy, client_secret= os.getenv("mysec"))
```

Attention:
The script is executed on different Databrick Workspaces where the secret scopes are named differently. So I can't use `dbutils.secrets.get` directly. However, the spark context name is identical on all cluster.